# What is causing this error when attempting to validate a JWT?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, oauth, jwt

I am trying to implement a [Google OAuth login](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button). After the user logs in using their Google account, a JWT token is posted to this endpoint in my Express server, which is parsed with [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken):

```
app.post('/login/google', express.urlencoded(), async(request, response, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(`${request.method} ${request.url} was called.`);
        let token: string = request.body.credential;
        let decoded = jwt.verify(token, Globals.GoogleSecret, { algorithms: ['RS256'], ignoreExpiration: false });
        response.sendStatus(200);
    }
    catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

The `token` parsed from the body looks fine (I was able to decode it on [jwt.io](https://www.jwt.io)).

The error it's catching is:

```
code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
function: 'get_name'
library: 'PEM routines'
reason: 'no start line'
message: 'error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line'
```

**Could anyone please shed some light as to what is causing this error and what I can do to fix it?**

Here is some further context:

- `Globals.GoogleSecret` is a string that is set to the ***Client secret*** string displayed under my ***OAuth 2.0 Client ID Credential*** in the [API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).
- I have an Angular web application hosted at http://localhost:4200/.
- The application has Google's OAuth post the credential to the Express server using `data-login_uri="http://localhost:1337/login/google"`.
- The application is running with debugging on Windows using VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. [This issue](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/400) got me thinking. I was using the wrong key. When you go to the [Credentials in the API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), there is a small icon on the right-hand side of your Credential for the OAuth 2.0 Client ID that has a tooltip on it saying, ***Download OAuth client***. Upon doing so, inspect the JSON file and you will see the following line:

```
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
```

If you browse to that URL, you will hit a JSON payload with certificates. Only one will work to decode and verify the JWT, so you must try them all until one succeeds. I also had to modify the certificate's text format for the `verify` function as follows:

```
let certificate: string = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;
```

The key here is to replace all of the `\n` characters with a real newline. Notice that I am using the specific backtick template literal `` ` ``. You will also need to get rid of whitespace in the literal, especially if you copy and paste the certificate you get from that endpoint into a code editor. Finally, I was able to pass this in to decode the JWT:

```
let decoded = jwt.verify(token, certificate, { algorithms: ['RS256'], ignoreExpiration: false });
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach is because I am not a huge fan of pinned certificates, but maybe its more or less correct. Feel free to shed some light on this matter. I am not sure what existing implementations that verify JWT's usually do, i.e. if they first attempt to fetch the certificates directly from the `auth_provider_x509_cert_url` or not. Maybe pinning is better in case that URL goes down or is unreachable. However, certificates can expire, and if so the downside is that your OAuth client goes down until you update the pinned certificate, so it may be better to fetch them as needed. If there is a better way, please let me know in the comments or post an answer.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs serves JSON, you must not replace anything manually there, but instead parse it properly.

Comment: @zerkms  Doable, but is Google going to be okay with constant calls to that endpoint? Also, what if communications go down for that API? I guess that means there's bigger problems.

Comment: Those certificates are valid for weeks, so if you do it once a week - you're fine.. Serving static content is not a problem given you're going to talk to their API anyway.